# SSIS 2008 how to use EXEC

Tags: sql, ssis

Im using SSIS 2008
i want to try and run the following SQL code:

```
declare @test nvarchar(100)
set @test = 'Select Distinct Area From dbo.udf_RiskManagementPlan('') Where Area   is not Null And Area   != ''';

if exists (select object_id from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('dbo.udf_RiskManagementPlan') and name = 'Area')  

exec sp_executesql @test

Else select Null As Area
```

It is working fine in SQL managment studio, but when i try and place it in OLEDB source i keep getting error regarding syntax

i tried placing the entire code in a variable value and just call that still gave same syntax error

i have feeling this has more to do with SSIS problem handling stored procedure and parameters then the syntax, but i cant seem find way around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in SSIS you can't put such expression in source. Split it into parts:

1. Put an SQL Task block with `EXEC dbo.udf_RiskManagementPlan`, set input/output parameters to get result (e.g. `@SQLTaskResult`)

   [image: Control flow]
2. On positive finish: set a variable `Source_SQL` to:
   `DTS.Variables["Source_SQL"].Value = 'Select Distinct Area From 
   '+DTS.Variables["SQLTaskResult"].Value+' Where Area  is not Null And Area   != ''`
3. On error /no procedure or other error/ set `Source_SQL` to `Else select Null As Area` similar way. Double click the right connection, and set `Value` to `Falure`
4. Proceed to Data Flow - set OLE DB to read source sql dynamically from a variable in `OLE DB Source Editor`